# Tkinter window configuring python error "of no return"

Tags: python, window, themes, tkinter

OK so I have this long program. I'm having a problem with the themes. By themes I mean, a specific function I built to change the background and text color when activated in Tkinter.
Here's a shortened version of the code:

```
 global theme
 theme = 0
 windows = []
 buttons = []
 labels = []
messageboxes = []
```

## Code...

```
    def flavor_0():
    global theme
    for w in windows:
        w.config(bg = 'black')
    for l in labels:
        l.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
    for b in buttons:
        b.config(activebackground = "grey", activeforeground = "white", bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
    for i in listboxes:
        i.config(bg = 'black', fg = 'white', relief = "ridge") 
    theme = 0
```

## More Code... ( I define the other flavors in this section)

```
def set_theme():
    global theme
    global register
    if theme == 0:
        flavor_0()
    elif theme == 1:
        flavor_1()
    elif theme == 2:
        flavor_2()
    elif theme == 3:
        flavor_3()
    elif theme == 4:
        flavor_4()
```

## Even More Code

```
    thememenu = Tkinter.Menu(menubar,tearoff = 0)
    thememenu.add_command(label="Plain",command = flavor_0)
    thememenu.add_command(label="Mint", command = flavor_1)
    thememenu.add_command(label="Strawberry", command = flavor_2)
    thememenu.add_command(label="Banana", command = flavor_3)
    thememenu.add_command(label="Peanut", command = flavor_4)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="Flavor", menu = thememenu)

    def windowinator():
        new = Tkinter.Tk()
        windows.append(new)
        set_theme()

    windowinator = Tkinter.Button(root,text="New Window", command = windowinator)
    windowinator.pack()
    buttons.append(windowinator)
```

OK finally done.
Now when I run this the theme changer works. Until I use "windowinator". As long as a window I have opened before is not closed, the theme can be changed without any problems. But when I do close just one of them and attempt to change the "theme": I get a plain (themeless window) and this awkward error :

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ahmet\Desktop\Fobby\FOBBY.py", line 70, in flavor_3
    w.config(bg = 'black')
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1202, in configure
    return self._configure('configure', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1193, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
TclError: invalid command name "."
```

So can anyone tell me what went wrong exactly?

Comment: some of your indentation is incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only ever create a single instance of the `Tk` class. It looks like what is happening is that the initial default window (".") is being destroyed. Tkinter is not designed to be used that way.

If you want multiple windows, create instances of `Toplevel`.

Comment: Now I get another error:
Exception in Tkinter callback
...
TclError: invalid command name ".44532640"

Comment: @madprogramer: That means you're trying to run a command on some widget that has been destroyed.

Comment: Okay, then is there command to check when a widget has been destroyed and perform a function?